# Python OpenCV not reading video input when launched through .exe

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

I'm currently trying to finalize my school's final job. It involves a simple GUI which I made in Tkinter to simplify file adding and saving, and an object detector YOLOv3 which is implemented using the OpenCV python library. I'm trying to make it in an .exe file using Auto-Py-2-Exe which is a PyInstaller with a GUI.
When the code is ran through basic Python IDE, it runs fine. The problem occurs when it's in an exe: OpenCV doesn't seem to recognize and read the file path Tkinter gives it. I tried changing codecs for the Video file (.mkv, .mp4) with no success. I've tried different versions of OpenCV (4.2 & 3.8). I made it print messages and it isn't the problem with GUI forwarding the path as the file path gets printed out completely fine in the start() - (Function made to analyze video) just before the cap.read() function.

The program crashed at the print frame.shape :

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The code that brings the error:

```
def start(filepath):
    print(f"filepath: {filepath}")
    W = None
    H = None
    print("### Loading yolo... ###")
    net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath,weightsPath)

    #net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
    #net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL)

    ln = net.getLayerNames()
    ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

    print("### Done loading... ###")

    print ("Begining to Analayze")
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(filepath)
    #cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        status,frame = cap.read()
        print(f"frame shape: {frame.shape}")
        frame = cv.resize(frame, (640,480))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wonders... The problem was caused by the PyInstaller not including the ffmpeg348_64.dll. After adding this library to the .exe location, the script worked.